# how to get number of files older than 1 hour on ksh HP-UX

Tags: find, ksh, hp-ux

I need to list set of files created older than 1 hour in certain folder of HP-UX. Following is the command i tried.

```
find . -type f -mmin +60 | wc -l
```

But it return following error for ksh

> find: bad option -mmin

What is the alternative option to get number of files older than 1 hour?

Even i tried following command. Still another error. But it also work on bash

```
find . -type f -mtime  +0.04 | wc -l
```

> find: Error in processing the argument 0.04

Comment: Use `touch` for creating a file of one hour old and use `find ! -newer tmpfile`

Comment: @sugunan wants files older, not newer, so your answer (and mine below) are not valid

Comment: Sorry, with ! operator it would work, but the correct command is find . ! -newer tmpfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find in HP-UX has no options for minutes, mtime takes days as argument.
You can create a testfile, "touch" it with the desired time and then compare with ! -newer[m]. For instance:

```
# onehourago=`date  +"%m %d %H %M" | awk '{ onehourago=$3 - 1 ; if (onehourago<0) { onehourago=59 } printf("%.2d%.2d%.2d%.2d\n",$1,$2,onehourago,$4) }'`

# touch -t "$onehourago" testfile

# find . -type f ! -newer testfile | wc -l
```

Comment: My answer is not valid because he wants files "older" than the testfile, and that is not possible, there is no "-older" option, as far as I know.

Comment: Edited and now is valid, with "!" operator

Comment: This is working fine on HP-UX. Only problem it counts testfile as well. But I will fix it. Any how thanks for the answer.